# Fingerprint sha256 has already been taken Fingerprint sha256 cannot be generated.KeyType isForbidden.Must beRSA,ED25519"I am Trying toCreate anSSH key

Tags: ssh, gitlab

I entered that key after entering this command `~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub` and this was the result

```bash
/c/Users/KULEH/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
/c/Users/KULEH/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub: line 1: `ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAIJjn/Ikrw1vmBN//SdSax5Fkfy1pTZtfo2mnr5l1z1Km <This one is more secure>'
```

And this is what I copied and pasted as my ssh key

```
ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAIJjn
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the public key you are copying is a full one complete line, without newline in the middle.

Copy it first to an IDE/text editor, with line numbers displayed, and make sure your full public key is one one *single* line.

Then you can copy that line to your GitLab SSH page.

Comment: ssh-ed25519AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAIJjnmm  I entered that one without spaces and the error is still there

Comment: @FaraiMatsika That does not look like a public key content (a bit short)

Comment: sow how cean i see the exact key

Comment: @FaraiMatsika I just tested `ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -P "" -f test`, and `test.pub` is short indeed, but does have a space between `ssh-ed25519` and the key itself: `ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAIOvZDyYzHCDZmD/V2k06W/HvSnFBOMpQaeDhA2L/M4FY vonc@vclp`. The trailing space followed by the username@hostname (like `... vonc@vclp)`is just a comment and can be copied or ignored (it does not matter)

Comment: @FaraiMatsika The point is: the public key is a bit longer than what you mention in the question.