# SSHKEY error (trying to get and use SSHKEY for gitlab)

Tags: gitlab, ssh-keys, ssh-keygen

(I have already seen other related answers in Stack Overflow, not helping, I may be missing something out)

I am getting this error after adding my SSH key to GitLab:

The form contains the following errors:

- Key is invalid
- Fingerprint sha256 has already been taken
- Fingerprint sha256 cannot be generated
- Key type is forbidden. Must be RSA, ECDSA, ED25519, ECDSA_SK, or ED25519_SK

This is my key generated from command prompt :

```
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
```

COMMAND:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "taha.gh1985@gmail.com"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to copy the *full* public key part of what `ssh-keygen` has generated.

In your case, the public key should start with `ssh-rsa AAA...`.
I [mentioned before a similar error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72946986/6309), where the key was incomplete.

Note: the GitLab error message "`Fingerprint sha256 has already been taken`" has been reported as "not helpful enough": [issue 377357](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/377357).

Comment: I must have copied the full text in rsa file. 
this is the right answer. thx @VonC

Comment: @iDeveloper Perfect, well done. I though the public key was "strange" ;)

Comment: @iDeveloper Note: the [bit after the last "`=`" is a comment](https://serverfault.com/a/743551), that can be left out. The [`=` itself is important](https://serverfault.com/a/358391).

Answer (score 1):

RSA file :

ssh-rsa AAAAB3Nz.....61E8U= pasar@DESKTOP-9SMOQR

I removed begin and end of text and used it as key to GITLAB which was the reason why SSHKEY was wrong.